# Regex: Numbers between special characters (but not all number)

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to solve a relatively simple parsing issue that regex seems like it would be great for. I'm still trying to wrap my head around the notation, so I was hoping to get a nudge in the right direction for what I'm trying to do. The string I have is in this format:

```
x = 'Testing - 12:34: I dont want this number at the end 4567:'
```

From what I've been able to write:

```
test = re.findall(r'\b(\d+)\b',x)
```

will give the output of

```
['12', '34', '4567']
```

It's close, but not quite there. The problem is not every string I'm going to be scanning at the end, so I'd like to have a regex statement rather than just

```
test = test[:2]
```

Essentially, the condition I'm trying to articulate is 'take the numbers between the - and second :, but nothing else.' (ie 12:34 in the form ['12','34]). Is this possible? Thank you!

http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%3b%5cd%2b%3d%5cd%2b%5c%3f&i=0014%3b5010730101000033347%3d4510120173%3fAA

Comment: Why don't you want the last number?

Comment: It's more a one off that happens in certain lines of the data that I'm parsing, but causes a huge mess. Maybe messing with the regex isn't the right answer and I should just eliminate the last few elements of the string for all of them to avoid the problem entirely?

Comment: My question was more along the lines of "what does this mean" : `The problem is not every string I'm going to be scanning at the end, so I'd like to have a regex statement `

Comment: Ah gotcha. I just meant that not every string will have this problem of having a number at the end (which is why the simple regex expression I wrote isn't working)...was just trying to demonstrate my motivation for solving it through regex.

Comment: @user6142489 Like [THIS](https://regex101.com/r/6OEUcd/3)?

Comment: Wow that's an awesome site - going to mess around with that - thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This might be **a lot** easier with two expressions:

```
import re

x = 'Testing - 12:34: I dont want this number at the end 4567:'

rx_outer = re.compile(r'-((?:[^:]*:){2})')
rx_inner = re.compile(r'\d+')

numbers = [number.group(0) 
            for match in rx_outer.finditer(x) 
            for number in rx_inner.finditer(match.group(0))]

print(numbers)
# ['12', '34']
```

The "outer" regex defines the slice between the first dash and the second colon while the "inner" regex scans for digits. The logic is wrapped in a list comprehension.